# OGR2OGR from mssql to geopackage

Tags: ogr2ogr

Im trying to export a table from MSSQL to geopackage using ogr2ogr:

This is the exact command I try in windows terminal (but with real serv,db,user,pass ofc):

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\ogr2ogr.exe -f "GPKG" C:/GIS/data/testdata/test123.gpkg MSSQL:database=somedbname;server=somesrv123;uid=userid;pwd=password;tables=sometable
```

I get errors:

> ERROR 1: Error initializing the metadata tables :
>   [37000][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]CREATE
>   TABLE permission denied in database 'somedbname'.(262)

and

> ERROR 1: No column definitions found for table 'sometable', layer not usable.

What am I doing wrong? I can connect to the db in QGIS and ArcMap and add table to the map.

```
ogrinfo MSSQL:database=somedb;server=somesrv;uid=user;pwd=password;tables=sometable
```

> ERROR 1: Error initializing the metadata tables : [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]CREATE TABLE permission denied in database
>   'somedb'.
>   and
>   ERROR 1: No column definitions found for table 'sometable', layer not
>   usable. INFO: Open of
>   `MSSQL:database=somedb;server=somesrv;uid=user;pwd=password;tables=sometable'
>         using driver`MSSQLSpatial' successful. 1: sometable

Adding the layer to QGIS and using OGR2OGR from QGIS generate errors:

> CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
>
> UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory.
>
> ERROR 1: Error initializing the metadata tables :
>   [37000][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]CREATE
>   TABLE permission denied in database 'somedb'.(262)
>
> ERROR 1: No column definitions found for table 'sometable', layer not
>   usable.
>
> ERROR 1: Couldn't fetch requested layer 'someschema.sometable'!

Comment: Does `ogrinfo ogr2ogr.exe  MSSQL:database=somedbname;server=somesrv123;uid=userid;pwd=password;tables=sometable` work as you suppose?

Comment: @user30184 i added output to the question. Seems in part successful?

Comment: Seems like ogr2ogr wants to read\create geometry_columns metadata table. Does you mssql database contains this table and records in it? Does your user have permissions to read this?

Answer (score 3):

ogr2ogr MSSQL Driver wants to read\create geometry_columns metadata table in you mssql database.

- You can create table geometry_columns and add record for your table to it.

OR

- You can set [config parameter](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mssqlspatial.html#configuration-options)  MSSQLSPATIAL_USE_GEOMETRY_COLUMNS to NO

```
ogr2ogr --config MSSQLSPATIAL_USE_GEOMETRY_COLUMNS NO -f GPKG test.gpkg MSSQL:database=somedb;server=somesrv;uid=user;pwd=password;tables=sometable
```

Comment: Less errors, now I only get: "ERROR 1: No column definitions found for table 'sometable', layer not usable."

Comment: try to set table parameter with geometry column name https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mssqlspatial.html#connecting-to-a-database - MSSQL:....tables=sometable(geometryColumn). Are you db in native geometry format? If it opening in arcmap - it can be in legacy arcgis geometry, where shape field contains key of geometry. Can you provide create table script?

Comment: also I have an issue with non-ascii characters in table name - driver not like this. For example any Cyrillic names in sql server profiler displayed like "[Р’С‹СЃРѕС‚РЅРѕСЃС‚СЊР¦РµРЅС‚СЂ]". You can try to rename table, or build view with ascii name behind this table.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
ogr2ogr --debug ON -sql "select top 100 * from table" -f "GPKG" -a_srs "EPSG:4269" test123.gpkg MSSQL:database=dbname;server=servername;trusted_connection=yes;GeometryFormat=native -nln nameinpackage
```

**NOTE**:

table not dbo.table in the sql query  -> i have had issues when using prefixes randomly

trusted_connection=yes can be replaced with trusted_connection=no;UID=user;PWD=pwd

GeometryFormat=native if geometry field is a geometry type in sql otherwise use one of: native|wkb|wkt|wkbzm

--debug ON to get debug messages

-a_srs "EPSG:4269" set the EPSG based on SRID for your data

Comment: I got the table but without geometries, nice! I dont know which geometry format to use, ill try some more. Do you know how to query the db to find out which geomtry type it is?

Comment: look at the schema of the table. Typically, you want to find out if your geometry is in text(wkt), binary(wkb), or geometry type (native). Try: SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name='nameoftable' and respond with what it returns for your geometry column.